# how to use cloud-init to install packages on a Raspberry pi 4?

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi, cloud-init

After flashing the  `ubuntu-18.04.4-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz` image from https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi there is a file on the drive called `user-data`.

I'm trying to use that file to install some packages using instructions found on https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#package-update-upgrade-install

I added the following to the `user-data` file:

```
package_update: true

packages:
  - i2c-tools
```

After booting I see `cloud-init` using apt to update sources when it fails:

```
cloud-init[1549]: Err:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe arm64 arm64 1.0.0~rc7+git20190403.029124da-0ubuntu~18.04.2
cloud-init[1549]:    404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
...
```

and it doesn't install the packages.

How do I use cloud-init to install packages?

Right after booting, I can log in and run `sudo apt install i2c-tools` and it works, so I'm connected to the Internet. (Ethernet btw)

Comment: Does `sudo apt update` from a shell work?

Comment: yes it does, along with `sudo apt install`

Comment: Have you ever solved that?